# Extracting info from Clearbit api using Python

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am somewhat new to Python, but getting better every day. I am trying to find company website url's using their company name. Clearbit has an api that allow you to get the info by adding the company name as a parameter in the the api url. My plan is to give it a list, and eventually output to a spreadsheet. First I need to make sure I can extract the info from the api output.

I am able print the info using this code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import ssl


companies = ['IBM','Apple']
companyinfo = []

for company in companies:

    #ignore SSL sert errors
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    serviceurl = "https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query="

    combined = serviceurl + company
    print(combined)
    #url =  urllib.parse.urlencode(combined)
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(combined, context=ctx)
    data = connection.read()
    print(data)
```

I tried to extract the data using this:

```
  domain = data[0]
  print(domain)
```

But that did not work. I feel like I am so close!  Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: what does `data` look like

Comment: @gold_cy here is the data when the loop gets to IBM: [{"name":"IBM","domain":"ibm.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/ibm.com"},{"name":"International Business Management Institute","domain":"ibm-institute.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/ibm-institute.com"},{"name":"IBM Security","domain":"securityintelligence.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/securityintelligence.com"},{"name":"IBMastery","domain":"ibmastery.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/ibmastery.com"},{"name":"IBMirror","domain":"ibmirror.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/ibmirror.com"}]

Comment: and what is the error you get when running your code

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, @gold_cy. If try to print `domain = data[0]
 print(domain)`, it prints: 91. If I try to print `domain = data[1]
 print(domain)`, it prints: 123. If I try to print `domain = data[0]['domain']
 print(domain)`, it prints: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: that doesn’t make sense, you said data is a list of dictionary but you are describing a list of int

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, @gold_cy. I don't understand. You can see what the data looks like. It is a list that has dictionaries in it. I don't know why it prints numbers. I don't know why when I try to print a key at the end of the list it comes out with an int error. My code is there, You can run it yourself. If you saw this data in your browser, how would you try to print the value for key ['domain'] which is in the 0 index position of this list?